# cannot get parameters from ajax call to controller razor

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

Simple usecase - get PartialView dynamically from AJAX call to update div in my main page after input select (dropdownlist) changed value.

Steps I took:

1. Created view (only, wihtout PageModel) with model declared with @model ViewModelCreateOperation.
2. Created checkbox on main page:

```
<select class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.allExistingOperations))" onchange="PopulateForm(this.value); return false;"></select>
```

3. created scripts on main page:

```
<script>

    function PopulateForm(value) {
        var dataToPost = "{ operationName:" + value + "}";;
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: '@Url.Content("/MeaningOfLifeRoutedName")',
                data: dataToPost ,
                contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#lubieplacki').html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    if (xhr.status == 404) {
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

4. created Controller in Controllers folder to return PartialView (becouse I cannot use "return PartialView("someview", someModel)" with PageModel already used as a inherit class.

```
namespace MyMysteriousApplication.Controllers
{
    [Route("MeaningOfLifeRoutedName")]
    public class MeaningOfLifeChangesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyMysteriousApplication.Models.TTSCDBContext _context;

        public MeaningOfLifeChangesController(MyMysteriousApplication.Models.TTSCDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public ViewModelCreateOperation viewModelCreateOperation { get; set; }

     
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("../Index");
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult getMeaningOfLife(string operationName)
        {
            viewModelCreateOperation = new ViewModelCreateOperation();


            viewModelCreateOperation = new ViewModelCreateOperation();
            viewModelCreateOperation._entitiesSelectListItem = _context.Entities
                                                                  .Select(a => new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem()
                                                                  {
                                                                      Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                                                                      Text = a.EntityName
                                                                  }).OrderByDescending(u => u.Text)
                                                                  .ToList();



            viewModelCreateOperation.MeaningOfLifeChanges = _context.MeaningOfLifeChanges.Where(u => u.OperationName.Contains(operationName)).OrderBy(u => u.ChangeId).FirstOrDefault();



            return PartialView("../projectManagement/partialViewCreateNewMOL", viewModelCreateOperation);
        }


    }

}
```

***Primary question:***
I got null in parameters - I don't get why:
[image]

***Bonus question:***
I couldn't invoke my controller in any way (tried "/MeaningOfLifeChangeController/getMeaningOfLife" or "/MeaningOfLifeChange/getMeaningOfLife", with "~/MeaningOfLifeChangeController/getMeaningOfLife" and others combinations), so I added [Route("MeaningOfLifeRoutedName")] and [HttpPost] before method. I don't get why...
in Startup I have added controllers to initialize (JSON is for other stuff(API)):

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().
         AddJsonOptions(options =>
         {
             options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
             options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
             options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 150;
         }).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not my answer, but Jiadong Meng helped me in ASP .NET Forums. I'm posting His answer:

Since the data  you want to send is just a string type data, you need to stringify it like below.

```
var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(value);
```

Then in your Action, you should also add [FromBody] attribute.

```
public ActionResult getMeaningOfLife([FromBody]string operationName)
```